# Set default option in dialogprompt

Tags: c#, botframework

I have this:

```
var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>(
    new string[] { "Yes", "No" },
    "Are you sure?",
    "Sorry, that wasn't a valid option",
    3
);
```

How do I set the dialog's default option to No?

Comment: Are you really asking "Are you sure?" If so, you could look at using PromptConfirm instead of PromptChoice